# How do I quickly explore objects in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

Using SSMS Object Explorer to click through explorer tree against a database with many tables, stored procedures, views, ... can be time consuming, and inefficient way to gain access to specific objects while developing.

Are there any tools to allow for quick access to objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Search (free from Red Gate) integrates right into SSMS

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm